# Function wait for the Query result

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, chatbot

I try to make the function `wait` for the Query result but I never get the result. I always have 
a Promise {Pending} and later the Query to Splunk Done is displayed. How do I make the program wait for the result?

I want to wait for the result and then send the result to a bot.

```
async function esperate () {
  var variable = splunk_normal(Query_splunk, () =>{
    console.log('Query to Splunk Done');
    //exports results from Splunk SDK
    const newLocal = myModule.resultados
    var results2 = newLocal;
    return results2;
  });

  console.log("one");
  return variable;
} 

var mirar = esperate();
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Hello,  did you solve your question?

Comment: im still searching a solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an await:

```
async function esperate ()
{
    var variable = splunk_normal(Query_splunk, () =>{ 
        console.log('Query to Splunk Done');

        //exports results from Splunk SDK
        const newLocal = await myModule.resultados // Here
        var results2 = newLocal;
        return results2;

    });
    console.log("one");

    return variable;
}

var mirar = esperate();
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: Hello Andres, i tried to add an await but it doesnt work, furthermore VS Code shows "await "has no efect on the type of this expression.